# copy contents from PROGMEM to const char []

Tags: c++, constants, avr, avr-gcc, progmem

What is the best way to copy a string form `PROGMEM` to a `const char[]`?

While something like this would probably work:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
const char *pstr = PSTR("Hello");
char str[strlen_P(pstr)+1];
strcpy_P(str, pstr);
const char *cstr = str;
```

Maybe there is a solution using an `initializer_list` object returned by a lambda with `pgm_read_byte` inside, similar to http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/213574/?

Comment: Don't forget that `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. Don't forget to add space for the null-terminator. Besides, your code is invalid C++ anyway, since C++ doesn't have [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: You're right about the '\0'. I changed the example.

Comment: To copy things we have [std::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).